# How to add a specific field in Spring Data Rest?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am developing a web service using Spring Data Rest.

```
public interface BookRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Book, Long> {

    @Override
    @Query("select avg(rl.rating) as rating, b from ReadingList rl join rl.book b group by rl.book order by rating desc")
    Page<Book> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

When I select in JPQL as above, 'avg (rl.rating) as rating' column does not have the name like the image below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FS0Q.png)

rating: 4.0
I would like to do this service.

In addition, the full source is in github.
https://github.com/ohgamja3/readinglist-rest-server/

I would like help with this issue.
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [projection](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts) in the output of your repo method.

1. So in your case you can set a projection, for example:

```java
@Projection(name = "BookWithRating", types = { Book.class }) 
interface BookWithRating { 

  Float getRating(); 

  Book getBook(); 
}
```

2. Then setup a query method:

```java
@Query("select avg(rl.rating) as rating, b as book from ReadingList rl join rl.book b group by rl.book order by rating desc")
Page<BookWithRating> findAllWithRating(Pageable pageable);
```

Pay attention to the alias of the output parameters - their names must match the projection getters.

Also you can try to use [this](https://spring.io/blog/2016/05/03/what-s-new-in-spring-data-hopper#projections-on-repository-query-methods) technics for enriching a data model (see how to 'annotate exposed properties with @Value using SpEL expressions to expose synthetic properties').

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
However, when @Projection is applied as above, an exception occurs at startup.
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: interface readinglist.BookWithRating

Comment: I've updated my answer. We cannot use 'findAll' фы the name of the query method with Page<BookWithRating> as the output of course. Also you use 'float' type for 'rating', so I change it in the projection. You can find a working projection example [here](https://bitbucket.org/Cepr0/projectionexample).

Comment: Thank you very much.
Thanks for your help.