# Child property in spring data jpa query is not working

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

We are using spring data jpa available with spring boot 1.5.3. In repository class I wanted to fetch only few columns from a table including data from child table (which is onetomany mapping) so, I wrote a method with query.
But that query method is not working and seeing below errors/warnings in logs

```
SQL Error: -104, SQLState: 42601
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=.;ARRAY + - ROW NEXTVAL PREVVAL NEXT PREVIOUS ( <INTEGER>, DRIVER=4.19.26
```

Here is my parent entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent_table")    
public Class Parent {
   // no-param constructor

   Parent(int id, String name, Child childData) {
      // assign these accordingly
   }
   // id, name, and couple of other mappings

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
   private Set<Child> childData;
}
```

Child entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child_table")
public class Child {
    // id and couple of other columns

    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "p_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Parent parent;

}
```

And repository is here:

```
@Transactional
public interface ParentRepository extends CrudRepository<Parent, Integer> {

    @Query("select new Parent(id, name, p.childData) from Parent p where p.id=?1")
    public Parent findOnlyChildDataById(final int id);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use custom method to get Entity by its 'id', use native method `findOne`:

```
public interface ParentRepository extends CrudRepository<Parent, Integer> {
}

@Service    
public ParentService {

    @Authoware
    prvate ParentRepository repo;

    public Parent getParentById(int id) {
        return repo.getOne(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, here I don't need all the columns in parent. So, I wrote custom method with jpa query.

Comment: If you need an entity without some properties then this is not an entity, it's a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) and you need another [technic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42946268) to deal with it.

Comment: Thank you. But, I am already using similar method given below in repo which is working fine.

@Query("select new Parent(id, name, application, anothercolumn) from Parent p where p.application=?1")
public List<Parent> findAllByApplication(String application)

I am getting problem only where I am including child property in the query.