# Springboot Pageable with Specification JPA problem

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest, pageable

i have a data problem for my code:

```
    PeopleSpec peopleSpec = new PeopleSpec(req.getSearchFilters(), jsonReqRes.getOrder());
    int currentPage = req.getCurrentPage() - 1;
    int elementForPage = req.getElementForPage() > 0 ? req.getElementForPage()
            : PrevConstants.ELEMENT_FOR_PAGE_DEFAULT;
    Page<ViewPeople> entityPage = null;

    entityPage = peopleRepository.findAll(peopleSpec, PageRequest.of(currentPage, elementForPage));
    entityList = entityPage.getContent();
    
    //custom remove duplicates from a field (contract)
    HashSet<Object> seen=new HashSet<>();
    entityList.removeIf(c -> !seen.add(Arrays.asList(c.getContract())));
    
    //here is the problem!!!
    //result list is different from entityPage results because i have removed data

    jsonReqRes.setResultList(resultList);
    jsonReqRes.setTotalPages(entityPage.getTotalPages());
    jsonReqRes.setTotalElements(entityPage.getTotalElements());
```

The rows has many (not all) equals fields and i removed it from a custom remove, after the result of the spec and my problem is the pagination because
resultList lenght is different from the collection that is in entityPage.

Thanks for the solution.

The spec has also the property distinct.

Comment: And your entities probably don't have a proper `equals` and `hashCode` methods. If they have, either your distinct is wrong, or you are doing weird things, but my primary guess is the missing methods.

Comment: @M.Deinum nono, the Tableview return for example: a,b,c for First row and a,b,d for second row. I want to delete the first or second

Comment: Then why use a pageable in the first place? That doesn't make sense and will actually also screw up your paging. Looks like you want a different query instead. Nonetheless I still don't really get why you need to filter those and looks like a query or implementation fault.

Comment: @M.Deinum i think that i can use query with Pageable but i have a custom query and not select * from tablet view...

Comment: It still is a query... It doesn't matter what you have, you have a specification written, which means you should write a proper one.

Comment: @M.Deinum i have a case for example:  select a,b,c from tableview where....   and the result will be a Pageable; a possibile solution is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927756/how-to-add-a-specific-field-in-spring-data-rest  but i dont know that is the best